# Which is the recommended approach to show data and receive it back in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Giving this simple model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public Person()
    { }

    internal void Save()
    {
    }
}
```

With this `cshtml`:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        Age of @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.Name) :   
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Age)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

And this `Controller` to show and save:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View(new Person(name: "Test", age: 1));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Person p)
    {
        p.Save();
        ViewBag.Message = "Did it";

        return View(p);
    }
}
```

With this example the user is presented with the name of the user and an input for its age, pretty much like this:

[image: Age of Test: 1]

In this case since I'm using `DisplayFor<T>` to show its `Name` property is not post back to my `Edit` inside the `Person` class.

I can circumvent this by [using a `HiddenFor<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010836/asp-net-mvc-3-collecting-passing-data-from-views-with-nested-collections-data) for `Name` but looks like it's not the right way to do this (because you have the info twice in the source).

So, what is the correct/recommended/common sense way to show a property and have it post back to `Controller`?

Comment: If the client is not providing the name, then it's a value that the server side is getting from somewhere before presenting it to the client in the first place. The server side can just retrieve this information again whenever it's needed.

Comment: @GendoIkari It's a dup, yes. I didn't want to retrieve again just because I thought it should came back in the model, like it does in the ASP.NET WebForms `<# Bind("Name")>`

Comment: Doing things like ASP.NET WebForms did them is generally not the way you want to go. It may be correct in some situations, but one of the big problems with WebForms was that it passed way too much data back and forth. The comment in that other post mentions this. All depends on where the data is coming from; if it's an expensive database query then obviously you'd rather pass it back and forth than retrieve it again. But if it's a simple session value, then I'd read it from session every time.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using `HiddenFor` -- in fact, that's probably how you *should* do it.  It would be weird if you were also using `EditorFor` or something like that, but since this is the only place that you indicate you'd like to post the data to that action, you're totally clear to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Thinking in the way pure raw HTML works really make sense.